# Консоль вывода Visual Sudio C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, консоль, события

в проекте Windows Forms(.Net Framework) c# можно открыть окно вывода(или это консоль отладки)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
можно увидеть то что я пишу через метод Console.WriteLine(...), но когда я создаю проект Windows Forms(Майкрософт) я почему-то не могу видеть то что я пишу через этот метод, в чём проблема и какие решения?

Comment: `Debug.WriteLine(...)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Как сказал комментатор Debug.WriteLine(...);